# Traversal Binary search tree with circular-queue

Tags: c, recursion, queue, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX_QUEUE_SIZE 15

typedef struct _Node {
    int data;
    struct _Node* left;
    struct _Node* right;
} Node;

typedef struct {
    int data[MAX_QUEUE_SIZE];
    int front, rear;
}queue;

void init_q(queue* q)
{
    q->front = 0;
    q->rear = 0;
}

int is_empty(queue* q)
{
    return (q->front == q->rear);
}

int is_full(queue* q)
{
    return ((q->rear + 1) % MAX_QUEUE_SIZE == q->front);
}

void enqueue(queue* q, int data)
{
    q->front = (q->front + 1) % MAX_QUEUE_SIZE;
    q->data[q->rear] = data;
}

int dequeue(queue* q)
{
    q->front = (q->front + 1) % MAX_QUEUE_SIZE;
    return q->data[q->front];
}

Node* insertBST(Node* root, int data) {
    Node* p = root;
    Node* parent = NULL;
    while (p != NULL) {
        parent = p;
        if (p->data < data) {
            p = p->right;
        }
        else {
            p = p->left;
        }
    }
    Node* newNode = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if (newNode != NULL)
    {
        newNode->data = data;
    }
    
    newNode->left = newNode->right = NULL;

    if (parent != NULL) {
        if (parent->data < newNode->data) {
            parent->right = newNode;
        }
        else {
            parent->left = newNode;
        }
    }
    return newNode;
};

void Inorder(Node* root, queue* q) {
    if (root == NULL) {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        Inorder(root->left, q);
        enqueue(q, root->data);
        //printf("%d", root->data);
        Inorder(root->right, q);
    }

    printf("Inorder Traversal : ");
    while (!is_empty(q))
    {
        printf("%d ", dequeue(q));
    }
    printf("\n");    
}

int main()
{
    queue* q;
    init_q(&q);
    Node* root = NULL;
    root = insertBST(NULL, 6);
    insertBST(root, 2);
    insertBST(root, 7);
    insertBST(root, 1);
    insertBST(root, 4);
    insertBST(root, 3);
    insertBST(root, 5);
    Inorder(root, &q);
    return 0;
}
```

Structure of Binary Search Tree what I made :

```
             6
          2     7
        1   4 
           3 5
```

So the result what I expected is :
`Inorder Traversal :  1 2 3 4 5 6 7`

But the result seems broken as below :
`Inorder Traversal : -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -24257920 390 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 1 Inorder Traversal : -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -24257920 390 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 3 Inorder Traversal : -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -24257920 390 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 5 Inorder Traversal : Inorder Traversal : Inorder Traversal : -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -24257920 390 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 7 Inorder Traversal :`

It seems I made a mistake in `inorder` function (a recursive doesn't work well I guess)

and the pointer issue maybe I guess.

What did I wrong and how should I modify my code?
(I will try to implement postorder and preorder after modify this code.)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There are these issues:

- The declaration of `q` in `main` should be `queue q` instead of `queue *q`. The `insertBST` expects as second argument a `queue*` not a `queue**`. Most IDE's will give a warning about that mistake.
- The implementation of `enqueue` is moving the wrong index. It should move `rear` instead of `front`.

Not a major problem, but:

- It seems likely you want to print the queue *after* having called `Inorder`, not *during*. I would suggest creating a separate function for printing the queue.
- When calling `malloc` [don't cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc). Do as follows

  ```
  Node* newNode = malloc(sizeof(*newNode)); // Don't cast
  ```
- When `malloc` fails, your code protects the assignment to `root->data`, but then let's the execution continue to set `root->left`, ...etc. Instead, you could exit:

  ```
  if (newNode == NULL) exit(1); // When malloc fails
  ```